# How to turn off postgresql case sensitive search?

Tags: postgresql, case-sensitive

I have a lot of sql query command that use "WHERE" clause, I have just wondered that my postgresql searching was case sensitive.

for example:

```
 Select * From myarea Where area_name = 'Jawa Barat1' --> not found
 Select * from myarea Where area_name = 'jawa barat1' --> found
```

How to turn off the case sensitive searching in postgresql?

Please don't suggest me to change the sql command to set to lowercase at both side.

expect postgresql to in-case-sensitive searching  (Mother = mother)

Comment: the datatype citext support case sensitive search, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a63c8a932469dd1805b10b6a4e7acf99)

Using `ILIKE` comparator, which (as the `LIKE` comparator) works also with wildcards (see fiddle)

```
Select * From myarea Where area_name ILIKE 'Jawa Barat1'
```

Or normalize string with `lower()` which converts all letters to non-capitals. You have to use it for both comparing literals:

```
Select * From myarea Where lower(area_name) = lower('Jawa Barat1')
```

Comment: is there any database setup for turning off the case sensitive search?.. I have a lot of sql commands need to be adjusted :(